# TridionPageProvider.GetContentByUrl throws null reference exception How do we specify the CD server?

Tags: 2013, dd4t

I am using DD4T to implement SDL Tridion.  I have 2 servers (in Datacenters)

1. Content Management (Server A)
2. Content Delivery (Server B)

I have created a DD4T template in my local machine. In the DD4T Web Site, i have copied the lib and config directories. Now I am getting a runtime Error.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013.TridionPageProvider.GetContentByUrl(String Url) +547
   DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page) +557
   DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.GetModelForPage(String PageId) +109
   DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.Page(String pageId) +22
```

I have few questions:

1. How the DD4T application finds the Content Delivery server (Server B),
   although it is not mentioned anywhere in the config file.
2. How to solve the above exception.
3. Can we provide Content Delivery URL in the DD4T Website and connect to it from Visual Studio, or do I need to set up a Content delivery instance in my local host environment?

Log errors

```
014-08-08 11:57:15,766 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>TryFindPage (/Test_Page
2014-08-08 11:57:15,813 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - about to load page from cache with key Page_/Test_Page_0
2014-08-08 11:57:15,814 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - finished loading page from cache with key Page_/Test_Page_0, page found = False
2014-08-08 11:57:15,814 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - about to load page content from provider with url /Test_Page
2014-08-08 11:57:15,820 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>GetContentByUrl(/Test_Page)
2014-08-08 11:57:15,820 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: about to create query
2014-08-08 11:57:24,228 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: created query
2014-08-08 11:57:24,307 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: added criteria to query
2014-08-08 11:57:24,307 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: about to execute query
2014-08-08 11:57:24,309 [21] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: executed query
```

Comment: Can you check that
- the DB server settings in storage config is pointing to the correct server (server b)
- you actually have a valid cd_license.xml for your dev environment (check your tridion log files for any license errors)

Comment: @HaraldHoffelinck 
i am pointing to the correct DB Server in the storage.config. and also No license erros in the log files.  I have updated question with log error details

Comment: Check the Tridion cd_core.log. The location (and loglevel) are configured in the `logback.xml` file in 'bin\config\logback.xml'

Comment: @AlbertRomkes ok, I will look into it and get back to you. Is there any good basic tutorials for understanding DD4T. 
I would like to thank you people for helping me out so quickly :).

Comment: Just google for 'DD4T' and you should be good to go. If you have any more questions, just post them on SO :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. DD4T is part of your website and runs on your Content Delivery (web)server. 
   In the 'bin\config\cd_storage_conf.xml' there is a reference to the
   so called 'Broker Database'. This is the Tridion Content Delivery Databases that
   DD4T uses to find it's content. So your call `GetContentByUrl` tries to find
   it's content in this Broker Database.
2. Check Harald's comment. Did you follow the documentation? Java installed? License?
   Etc.
3. You can run/develop a DD4T website on any supported OS. You can either point your
   Visual Studio solution to an IIS website or use the build in webserver.

Comment: So you mean, WebSite has to deployed in the Deliver server. From Visual studio i can connect to that website for developing and building. am i right ?

Comment: No. Your website (with DD4T) can also run on your local machine, but your OS must be supported (check the docs) and your license should be valid *for your machine*. Also, your machine should be able to connect to the broker database.